# Visual Studio One Click URL Case sensitivity error

Tags: deployment, web, oneclick

I'm receiving an error when trying to download a published visual studio application. The error I get is

> - Downloading  did not succeed. [mywebsite]
> - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The directory where the file resides starts with a lower case letter (directory) but it's looking for the file in a directory with a capital letter (Directory).

The obvious solution is to change the case of the directory, however when I do this I get the same error with a different directory.

I've tried cleaning my solution and completely rebuilding it. No such luck.

So what can I do about this? Can I force oneclick to use all lowercase? All capitals?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. One of my model.X files referenced a texture from the directory using /textures/ instead of /Textures/. It caused no problems on the windows side of things, since it isn't case sensitive, but my web server is *nix based so it is.